# Header on first page with \scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, titles, scrlayer-scrpage

I'm trying to make a header on the first page above the title. The problem is that it does not show up on the first page but only starts on the second page. How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\ihead{left}
\chead{middle}
\ohead{right}

\title{title}
\author{name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine `\titlepagestyle`:

```
\renewcommand{\titlepagestyle}{scrheadings}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\renewcommand{\titlepagestyle}{scrheadings}

\ihead{left}
\chead{middle}
\ohead{right}

\title{title}
\author{name}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me @esdd.